# Ответ в виде текста при выполнении функции PHP

Tags: json, php, ajax

Добрый вечер.

Есть такой AJAX скрипт простой:

```
function go_news ( id )
    {
    var go_id = id;
    var search = 'id_go';
    $.post('site.php', { go_id: go_id, search: search }, function(data){
     $('#info').html(data);
        });
    return false;
};
```

И php файл:

```
if ($_POST['search'] == 'id_go') {

//Замена
$go_id = str_replace('', '', $_POST['go_id'])

//И так далее

//а тут уже конечный ответ к примеру
echo $go_id;
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы когда выполнялись функции в php, мне был ответ в виде текста, какой этап сейчас выполняется в

```
<div id="info">Тут ответ и результат потом уже</div>
```

?

У меня есть функция для php, и не могу понять, как с AJAX ее применить.

```
function printJson($info, $error = false) {
    @header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );

    if (!$error) {
        echo $info;
        return null;
    }

    $json = array( 'text' => '<span>' . $info . '</span>' );
    echo json_encode( $json );
    exit(  );
}
```

Comment: Поясните поподробнее, что вы хотите?
Особенно не понятен вопрос:"Как сделать, чтобы когда выполнялись функции в php, мне был ответ в виде текста, какой этап сейчас выполняется в...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял, это типа "Выполнено 5 %. Идет копирование того-то".

Схема такая:

1. Вы отправляете AJAX запрос на скрипт, который выполняет действия - назовем его do.php.
2. В AJAX настраиваете, что пока запрос не завершился, выполняете  функцию. Функция отправляет раз в 5 секунд запрос на другой скрипт - назовем его report.php. Суть этого скрипта в том, чтобы читать из источника (файла, бд, кэшь) информацию о выполнении скрипта do.php, который во время выполнения туда информацию и записывает.